# Hibernate Oracle INTERVAL EXPRESSION and Oracle 11g Dialect

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, formula, intervals

I need to use a INTERVAL EXPRESSION for a calculated field. like below:

```
@Formula(" SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR * SHOW_LIMIT_HOURS ")
private Date showLimitDate;
```

However, hibernate produces the following SQL fragment considering this expression like a column.

```
and product0_.sold_at > (
                SYSDATE - settings0_.INTERVAL '1' settings0_.HOUR * setting0_.SHOW_LIMIT_HOURS
            )
```

Anybody could help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days suffering, analysing AST processing of hibernate source code i finally gave up !! =P .. In fact there isnt a Oracle 11g Dialect available yet.

So , I changed the strategy and solve it with following changes :

**1. Create the follow function on Oracle database**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INTERVAL_HOURS_AGO(HOURS_PARAM IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
   IS TIME_AGO DATE;
   BEGIN 
      SELECT (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR * HOURS_PARAM) INTO TIME_AGO FROM DUAL;
      RETURN(TIME_AGO); 
    END;
```

DETERMINISTIC HINT on function is very important for avoid performance issue when use it on Where-Clauses. More infos about it on link:
http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/caution-when-using-plsql-functions-in-sql-statement/

**2. Create a Custom Oracle Dialect Class And Register the new Function.**

```
public class Oracle11gDialectExtended extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public Oracle11gDialectExtended() {

        super();

       registerFunction("interval_hours_ago", 
           new StandardSQLFunction("INTERVAL_HOURS_AGO", StandardBasicTypes.DATE));

    }
}
```

So, just call it on @Formula :

```
@Formula(" INTERVAL_HOURS_AGO( SHOW_LIMIT_HOURS ) ")
private Date showLimitDate;
```

Or on HQL / NamedQuery :

```
select p from Product p 
  where p.createdAt > interval_hours_ago(60)
```